# PHP; Passing a UTF-8 string via include/require

Tags: php, utf-8

I have the following function;

```
function generateFirstName(){
        $firstNameArray = array("Thomáš ","Lukáš ");
        $firstNameKey = mt_rand(0,1);
        $firstName = $firstNameArray[$firstNameKey];
        return $firstName;
    }
```

When the function is called on the same page the UTF-8 format outputs fine, but when it is called from a functions.php (that is REQUIRED in the INCLUDED head.php) the UTF-8 format doesn-t arrive and i get the dreaded black diamond with white question mark.

What do I need to do to pass the strings?

Comment: Check if all files are saved as UTF-8.

Comment: @panther, thx, have checked but will do again!

Comment: I can assure you that file inclusion has no bearing whatsoever on encodings. Something else is going on here which we cannot reproduce with the information given.

Comment: @deceze, you know that you are right. And now so do I. A problem with my IDE. Apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check every required or included files encoding. They all must be in UTF-8 to work together. You have to be sure about every file, that can be included from functions.php and other files.

Comment: Thx. This problem signals a Programmer error not a PHP issue. I had checked and then on double checking I saw Notepad++ encodes in 2 different places. My bad. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

Each file must be encoded in utf8